# Unhandled SQLite Exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, unhandled-exception

I am following a youtube video that makes a basic C# console app that will create and write to a SQLite database. The code in the video executes but I am getting an unhandled exception that states that {"SQL logic error or missing database\r\ntable Mytable has no column named Name"}

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SQLiteProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string createQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                                    [Mytable] (
                                    [Id} INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                    [Name] NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
                                    [Gender] NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";
            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("sample.db3");
            using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=sample.db3"))
            {
                    using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd=new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.CommandText = createQuery;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Mytable(Name,Gender) values('Brett','male')";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Mytable";
                        using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"]+ ":" + "reader['Gender']");
                            }
                            conn.Close();
                        }

                     }
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least you have a typo in the create section

Comment: SQLite does not use brackets

Comment: I just caught that. Now it does what it is supposed to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the CREATE TABLE area caused an issue with the brackets and curly braces. Section should read:

```
string createQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                                    [Mytable] (
                                    [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                    [Name] NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
                                    [Gender] NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";
```